# How do I create a mount point on the RAID1 that is persistent or always there, then prove it?

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, persistence

Repurposing an old server to be a backup repository. Name of box is backup. Ubuntu ver 20.04, command line only.
How do I make sure the files I copy to it from other servers using XCOPY or SCOPY are actually going to the RAID1?
How do I create a mount point on the RAID1 that is persistent or always there?
Or do I already have a mount point and do not know it?
How can I make it happen and prove it is working?

```
administrator@backup:/$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdd1: UUID="575d15f5-baf3-a6c9-d4e7-06731d2a572f" UUID_SUB="d3c74a79-10cb-8b83-049c-e572937372c3" LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="zfs" PARTUUID="688d0417-71b5-e344-8585-47c0fb46d70f"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="2c6f544c-641e-497a-b7c0-fdf9fb6a852f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c96406c3-6ac8-4900-81f6-da5eae388401"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="vbmVlD-2ojg-J3ix-5LlO-OHeE-SCoc-slDK09" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="16dfbb75-6f43-4fd4-a828-8eabaceb70a0"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="57974447-8c11-439f-82d4-b568b81cf9b0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sde1: UUID="575d15f5-baf3-a6c9-d4e7-06731d2a572f" UUID_SUB="7af91490-42b4-c693-f1d2-74d09f82a234" LABEL="ubuntu-server:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="zfs" PARTUUID="4dc3f453-abe2-264b-b050-894af7419e58"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdd9: PARTUUID="9737236d-165d-414c-bd20-1d3907c6447a"
/dev/sdb1: PARTUUID="534152da-4d51-4886-a795-77d5b4e4335f"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/md0p1: PARTLABEL="gpt" PARTUUID="421a3afd-c8e4-4579-bad2-6e394bb62620"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sde9: PARTUUID="a3876f14-b210-b84a-a364-4a2964e6a38a"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="af63730e-01"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: A mountpoint needs to be created on every server that is going to access your RAID. It is not created on the RAID. A mountpoint is a directory, so you need to create a directory with the same name on every server and add a corresponding line to `/etc/fstab` on every server. Tip: use `lsblk `f` instead of `sudo blkid` to get more useful output.

Comment: Thank you. I have one server. I am attempting to use it as a backup repository. All other devices are windows servers. When I save files to it, I think they are not going to the RAID but on to the boot drive. How do I make sure I can get the flies to save to the md0p1 partition.